# "Add to Home Screen" pop up in a non PWA web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Is it possible to have a pop up for "Add to home Screen" in a web app that is not a PWA app.? If yes then how to go about it. I tried some solutions from the below link in stackoverflow but it seems it only works via the browser option "Add to home screen" and is not triggering a Pop Up.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen)?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from MDN.

> ## How do you make an app A2HS-ready? To enable your app to be added to a Home screen, it needs the following:
>
> - To be served over HTTPs — the web is increasingly being moved in a more secure direction, and many modern web technologies (A2HS
>   included) will work only on secure contexts.
> - To have a manifest file with the correct fields filled in, linked from the HTML head.
> - To have an appropriate icon available for displaying on the Home screen.
> - Chrome additionally requires the app to have a service worker registered (e.g., so it can function when offline).

> ## PWA
>
> In order to call a Web App a PWA, technically speaking it should have the following features:
>
> - Secure contexts (HTTPS)
> - Service workers
> - Manifest file

As we can clearly tell from the above quotes, Add To Home Screen feature only differentiates in one way from a PWA, *Service Workers*. In Chrome though, you also need a service worker to enable A2HS. Since Chrome is the most popular browser and most of the other browsers are also based on Chromium, it is safe to say that the A2HS feature is only available for PWAs to most of the users.

**See:**

- [PWAs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps)
- [Add to home screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen)